# Decaffeinated: Double Brackets

Tags: javascript, if-statement, coffeescript

I decaffeinated an old project recently and I noticed that I got a lot of `if clauses` where the expressions are wrapped in "extra" brackets:

```
if ((data == null) || (data === ""))
```

Is there any case where the wrapping is required? Imho it is the same as:

```
if (data == null || data === "")
```

Comment: Yes, with "decaffeinated" I meant converting coffee to js:
https://github.com/decaffeinate/decaffeinate

Comment: It's not *required* but it does help when reading the code, as it can more clearly show the different parts of the condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case it wouldn't matter, but whenever you remove parentheses from an `if` statement (or anywhere pretty much) make sure you check the [precedence table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).

For example, removing the parentheses from this:

```
if ((someVar && someConditional) == someBool)
```

Would result in:

```
if (someVar && someConditional == someBool)
```

Which is completely different. The first example, due to the parentheses, will evaluate `someVar && someConditional` first, then `resultOfOperation == someBool`. In the second example, due to the higher precedence of `&&`, `someConditional == someBool` is evaluated first, then `0 && resultOfOperation`.

Answer (score 1):

With an explicit check, you could omit the parentheses around the comparisons, because of the lower [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) of [`==`/`===`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) over [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()).

```
if (data == null || data === "")
```

Comment: It's not just a string value it could be a String, Number, Object that's why I want to keep the `==` to just check for `undefined` or `null` and in the case of a string for an empty string.