# Precedence If Clause Parenthesis and Equality

Tags: javascript, node.js

Parenthesis have higher precedence than equality.

So from my understanding, the higher precedence is evaluated first.

Lets now assume I compare `a` which is not defined:

```
if (a == 1) { .. // throws an exception because a is not defined
```

Actual case:

```
if (typeof a !== 'undefined' && (a == 1)) {
  console.log(1)
} else {  
  console.log(2)
}
```

should be evaluated in this order:

1. (typeof a !== 'undefined' && (a == 1))
2. (a == 1)
3. typeof a
4. result from (3) !== 'undefined'
5. "result from (4)" && "result from (2)"

But this would usually throw an exception if a is not defined but it doesn't.

Why is the left side of the equation evaluated first even though it has the lower precedence?

EDIT: I adapted the example from '||' to `&&` just because `||` would always throw.

Comment: Parens don't add "weight", they group operations together that normally wouldn't be: `a || b && c || d` vs `(a || b) && (c || d)`

Comment: Where are you getting the values of precedence from?  If statements literally go from left to right, comparing the results (regardless of the type).

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Comment: In grade school arithmetic classes, they conflate the ideas of operator precedence and order of evaluation -- in something like `3 + 4 - (5 + 6)`, they tell you to compute `5 + 6` and then `3 + 4 - 11` -- which is fine because order of evaluation doesn't matter in arithmetic as long as you respect operator precedence. But in programming, where order of evaluation often *does* matter (because expressions can have side effects), you need to keep these concepts separate; respecting operator precedence isn't enough.

Comment: Okay - that would only affect calculations prior to the `if` statement running left to right.  `if (2 + 3 * 4 == 3 * 2 + 1)` would correctly calculate `if (14 == 7)` but then it's just an `if` statement.  Left to right - always.

Comment: @ruakh probably country dependant. I was taught that you'd need to eliminate the brackets to use the contents within, true, but it's not necessarily the *first* thing you do. So you can sum the first parts `3+4 = 7` and *in parallel* sum `5 + 6 = 11`. So, the next step in the evaluation is `7 - 11`. You just don't do something like a `3 + 4 - 5 + 6` all in one go but keep the parts of the equation separate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`||` is evaluated [left-to-right](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table):

> 5  Logical OR  left-to-right   … || …

So the inner expression that gets evaluated first is `typeof a`, as part of `typeof a !== 'undefined'`.

If the right-hand side of the `||` contains more expressions nested in parentheses, regardless of their operator precedence, they will only be evaluated after the left-hand side of the `||` has been evaluated.

Comment: Isn't `&&` also evaluated left to right?  Isn't every `if` statement?

Comment: Yep, *most* things are evaluated left to right, like you can see on the MDN link (though it's *per expression*, rather than *per statement*)

Comment: Yes, but shouldn't be the inner parenthesis with precedence `20 ` be evaluated over the `5`?

Comment: @AndiGiga No, the outer expression is the `||`, so the left-hand side of the `||` will be evaluated before anything on the right, no matter the precedence of any of the operators that happen to be nested on the right

Comment: But wouldn't than be `if (someVar && (someConditional == someBool))` equal to `if (someVar && someConditional == someBool)`.

Comment: `typeof a !== 'undefined' && (a == 1)` can be seen as `(typeof a !== 'undefined' && (a == 1))`. The outer expression is still `(foo && bar)`. `foo`gets evaluated first.

Comment: I came to this question, from the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56882749/decaffeinated-double-brackets

Comment: @AndiGiga Yes, those two expressions are equivalent, because `==` has higher priority than `&&` already

Comment: The answer you linked has been updated, @AndiGiga. It's now correct.

Comment: @AndiGiga I had already put a comment on that answer since yesterday showing it was incorrect. Maybe I should have been more explicit in calling this out but I ran out of characters for the comment...